# How to parse a string of a yaml file's content in Go?

Tags: json, string, go, parsing, yaml

I have a json response where I need to extract the list of values for **files** and **folders**, however both the number of elements in each list and properties in the json response is not fixed as shown below:

JSON Response:

```
"config.yml" : "project: \n  files: \n    - file1\n    - file2\n  folders: \n    - folder1\n    - folder2\n  random1: \n  random2:\n    - redundant1"
```

How can I parse the string and extract the list for files and folders into a []string?

For reference: config.yml

```
project: 
  files: 
    - file1
    - file2
  folders: 
    - folder1
    - folder2
  random1: 
  random2:
    - redundant1
```

I tried just yaml.unmarshalling the string (https://go.dev/play/p/j0RvgHo3djI) but that doesn't work.

I'm moving on to try yaml.unmarshalling the string, then json.marshal and json.unmarshal to get a nested map but I am not sure if this is the right way to go about it.

Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you show the code for what you've tried?

Comment: To be even more clear, welcome to SO! What exactly have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (in the body of your post, not linked to a 3rd party site, though of course that can be an ideal supplement)

Comment: @coxley updated above! Haven't finished coding up the unmarshalling and marshalling part yet though

Comment: The yaml library you're using doesn't like the yaml string.  If I add hyphens, it parses fine (although doesn't fill in your `struct`, probably because of the `project` wrapping: https://go.dev/play/p/FJscGHHp7bd.  I don't know yaml well enough to know whether the input you're using is valid or not, but this doesn't smell like an issue with your code to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished by tweaking your existing code — there are two issues with it:

1. It's unmarshaling into `[]MyStruct` but there's only one `project`. The files and folders are the only slices you need.
2. It's not considering `project` at all. The decoder currently expects `files` and `folders` to be at the top-level of the YAML document.

Here is the fixed version:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/goccy/go-yaml"
)

func main() {
    yml := "project: \n  files: \n    - file1\n    - file2\n  folders: \n    - folder1\n    - folder2\n  random1: \n  random2:\n    - redundant1"
    var resp MyStruct
    if err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(yml), &resp); err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Errorf("could not parse yaml from file. %w", err))
    }

    fmt.Println(&resp)
}

type MyStruct struct {
    Project struct {
        Files   []string `yaml:"files"`
        Folders []string `yaml:"folders"`
    } `yaml:"project"`
}
```

**Play**: https://go.dev/play/p/r8Q0kSx3NVc

Comment: Thank you! Still trying to get my head around Go…